# Can you define a generic bound that both has lower and upper bounds?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to define a generic bound that:

- implements an interface `SomeInterface`
- is a superclass of some class `MyClass`

Something like:

```
Collection<? extends SomeInterface & super MyClass> c; // doesn't compile
```

Comment: For the sake of records, Angelika Langer offers an interesting point of view in [this article](http://angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107) as to why *lower bounds* on class type parameters practically makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), the answer would be no (you can have `super` or `extends`, but not both):

> ```
>  TypeArguments:
>     < TypeArgumentList >
>
> TypeArgumentList: 
>     TypeArgument
>     TypeArgumentList , TypeArgument
>
> TypeArgument:
>     ReferenceType
>     Wildcard
>
> Wildcard:
>     ? WildcardBoundsopt
>
> WildcardBounds:
>     extends ReferenceType
>     super ReferenceType
> ```

Comment: I think the answer is as simple as you have phrased it. The other answer waffled on, but did not actually offer a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use generic type (`T` in your case) with bounds when declaring a variable.

It should be either a wildcard (`?`), or just use the full generic type of the class.

E.g.

```
// Here only extends is allowed
class My< T extends SomeInterface >
{

  // If using T, then no bounds are allowed
  private Collection<T> var1;

  private Collection< ? extends SomeInterface > var2;

  // Cannot have extends and super on the same wildcard declaration
  private Collection< ? super MyClass > var3;

  // You can use T as a bound for wildcard
  private Collection< ? super T > var4;

  private Collection< ? extends T > var5;

}
```

In some cases, you may tighten the declaration by adding extra generic parameter to a class (or method) and adding a bound on that particular parameter:

```
class My <
  T extends MyClass< I >,
  I extends SomeInterface 
>
{
}
```

Comment: Alex - you're right about the `T` - I changed it to `?`. (It was for illustrative purposed only)